# Rails 5, access params hash

Tags: parameters, ruby-on-rails-5, strong-parameters

I think I'm loosing it here ... so I have a params hash, that I want to use in a controller:

*Parameters:
{"utf8"=>"✓",  "_method"=>"patch",  "authenticity_token"=>"etcetc",  "scan"=>   {"1"=>{"scan_id"=>"40", "organisation_id"=>"1", "select_scan"=>"false", "role"=>""},    "2"=>{"scan_id"=>"40", "organisation_id"=>"2", "select_scan"=>"false", "role"=>""},    "3"=>{"scan_id"=>"40", "organisation_id"=>"3", "select_scan"=>"false", "role"=>""},    "number"=>"222",    "description"=>"nice!",  "expert"=>"for dummies",    "decentralisation"=>"0"},  "commit"=>"Update Scan",  "id"=>"40"}*

Now, if return to my view an instance variable, with value:

```
@q = params[:id]
```

that gives me '40', as expected.

```
@q = params['id']
```

also give me '40'

BUT, that's the only param value I can access? Every other value gives me nil, or an error like:

```
 @q = params[:scan][:number] # => undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
@q = params['scan']['1'][:role] # => undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
    @q = params[:scan].to_a # => []
@q = params[:scan].class # => NilClass
```

I've read about strong params, and all params are permitted, but still, no values are returned?

Answer (score -1):

Just a though but as far i could see, your hash structure is under quotes(" ") and your`re trying to access it with symbols(:) whithout .with_indifferent_access

e.g:

```
@q = params['scan']['number'] 
@q = params['scan']['1']['role'] 
@q = params['scan'].to_a
@q = params['scan'].class
```

Give a try.

Comment: No go, only `params[:id]` (and/or `params["id"]`) returns a value. But the good news is that I do succeed now in creating/saving objects with attribute values from the params hash, so the urge to solve this riddle has become a little less. Still, I really would like to know what is happening here ..